# Objects vs. Static Variables for retaining function state

Tags: c++, object, static

I have a function which processes data that comes as a sequence. Because of this, I need to know the value of certain variables from the last function call during the current function call.

My current approach to doing this is to use static variables. My function goes something like this:

```
bool processData(Object message){
    static int lastVar1 = -1;

    int curVar1 = message.var1;
    if (curVar1 > lastVar1){
        // Do something
    }

    lastVar1 = curVar1;
}
```

This is just a small sample of the code; in reality I have 10+ static variables tracking different things. My gut tells me using so many static variables probably isn't a good idea, though I have nothing to back that feeling up.

My question: Is there a better way to do this?

An alternative I've been looking into is using an object whose fields are lastVar1, lastVar2, etc. However, I'm not sure if keeping an object in memory would be more efficient than using static variables.

Comment: you dont need an object with members called `lastVar1`, `lastVar2` etc. in addition to the current object. You need a class with members `Var1`, `Var2` etc and two objects `current` and `previous` and if the method needs both the caller should pass them both instead of burying that inside the function making it basically untestable

Comment: object with member would be easier to test, and allow to call the method from several contexts (reentrency problem with static, ...).

Comment: A static local variable makes the function non-reentrant, which could matter if you want to run the code in multiple threads.

Comment: This function should be a class method, and the class method should have a private class member, that's used for this purpose. After all, this is what C++ is for: classes.

Comment: Mutable static state is almost never the right answer; it's quite often a crutch to hold up a design -- but ironically it often cripples it. `static` state can make it hard to unit test since state may carry over between tests, hard to create multiple instances (since they now implicitly share state), non-reentrant, etc. You're better off using a structured design that just records the `previous` and `current` state -- if not for your own sanity, then at least for the sanity of any future maintainer

Comment: static memory is static memory.  whether it is an int or an "object" (struct) containing that int doesn't make a difference.  If you had multiple instances of a class and they each needed to track DIFFERENT lastVar1, you could make lastVar1 and processData members of the class and each instance would have its own lastVar1.  This is done to factor code so you don't have to maintain multiple processData functions that are essentially copy pasted code.

Comment: Consider using 'memoization' within your object ... perhaps as a vector of previous objects, accessed thru back() and/or [size]

Comment: As for the unit test/re-entry folks, it all depends on what the function is supposed to do.  Letting unit test capability limit your architecture is a poor architecture for your code development system.  I'd suggest redesigning the unit test mechanism if such a need arose.

Answer (score 1):

Your question has a taste of being purely about style and opinions, though there are aspects that are not a matter of opinion: multithreading and testing.

Consider this:

```
bool foo(int x) {
    static last_val = -1;
    bool result = (x == last_val);
    last_val = x;
    return result;
}
```

You can call this function concurrently from multiple threads but it wont do the expected. Moreover you can only test the function by asserting that it does the right thing:

```
   foo(1);
   assert( foo(1) );    // silenty assumes that the last call did the right thing
```

To setup the preconditions for the test (first line) you already have to assume that `foo(1)` does the right thing, which somehow defeats the purpose of testing that call in the second line.

If the methods need the current object and the previous object, simply pass both:

```
bool processData(const Object& message,const Object& previous_message){

    if (message.var1 > previous_message.var1){
        // Do something
        return true;
    }   
    return false;
}
```

Of course this just shifts the issue of keeping track of the previous message to the caller, though thats straight-forward and requires not messing around with statics:

```
 Object message, old_message;
 while ( get_more( message )) {
     processData(message, old_message);
     old_message = message;
 }
```

Comment: Unfortunately I may have oversimplified my code. The reason I don't simply pass in old_message is because there's a non-trivial amount of processing that has to be done in order to get the value of curVar1 and others. That processing would have to be done twice if I were to pass in old_message

Comment: @Star-lordX no you dont have to do it twice, you do it once and pass it twice to the method. The answer only changes slightly, the signature would be `bool processData(Object message, Preprocessed current, Preprocessed previous)`